# Parity encryption password help

Tags: parity, password, encryption

```
{
"id":"eca798d8-8e68-a096-a35f-174133f86e43",
"version":3,
"crypto":
{
    "cipher":"aes-128-ctr",
    "cipherparams": { "iv":"45092c0a2032250e66a9d0bd2a33acaa" },
    "ciphertext":"0385fd52dfc528713d7b0b72073b992b93aa78f32b0576848a9de69d6e836c3d",
    "kdf":"pbkdf2",
    "kdfparams":
    {
        "c":10240,
        "dklen":32,
        "prf":"hmac-sha256",
        "salt":"e04e80b6174ca47c86e9174fd952949e53c900852d5c3cb62b863c5241e54f    28"
    },
    "mac":"178d2c012e1970b853e1551fa9bb0a51b86955cc4ed8db53a9b60cbbdbca8c7b"
},
"address":"00faf16e4909296f5cca76e1ccd7cd811fba93d0",
"name":"User-007",
"meta":"{}"
```

}

The Parity software creates an account in the localhost of the user when they install Parity. This means that the account info including password is stored in the owner's computer, right? The example above is what i found from another question but similar to what is found in the parity folders.

So I created an account to test if we can retrieve the password, without using the password recovery. I found that there is this file which i assume that there is the password in it, somewhere in the ciphertext or pbkdf2 encrypted texts. Is there a way to retrieve the password, and where do i start to?

I looked around and found out that the ciphertext contains the private key, but not the password. The pbkdf2 uses the password to hash, does that mean that there is a way of retrieving the password from the pbkdf2 salt / mac?

Comment: Actually, it's a feature that you can _not_ retrieve the password. The password is there to protect your account and it decrypts your private key. Vice versa wouldn't make any sense unless you want to hack accounts.

Answer (score 1):

> This means that the account info including password is stored in the owner's computer, right?

No, password is not stored.

> does that mean that there is a way of retrieving the password from the pbkdf2 salt / mac?

There is no easy(feasible) way. This is by design (as @afri commented).
You can read more about eth keystore file here:

https://medium.com/@julien.maffre/what-is-an-ethereum-keystore-file-86c8c5917b97